# How to get ASE(App Service Environment)'s internal ip address using Az Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

With the new Az module for Azure, does anyone know how to get the IP address of ASE(App Service Environment)? Like in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1O6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell cmdlet, to pull the Inbound & Outbound Ip Addresses of App Service in App Service Environment.

**Here is the PowerShell Cmdlet:**

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/sites -ResourceGroupName '<ResourceGroupName>' -Name 'ASEName' -ApiVersion 2021-02-01 `
|select -ExpandProperty properties `
|ft @{l="OutboundIPAddresses";e={$_.OutboundIPAddresses -split ","}},@{l="InboudIpAddresses";e={$_.inboundIpAddress -split ","}}
```

**Here is the sample Output screenshot for reference:**

[image]